# Display square and round brackets using Format[]

Tags: output-formatting

I am using Format to output functions in a nicer way. I want to be able to use round and square brackets in my output, e.g.

`Format[f[x_,y_]]:= (x[\CenterDot]y)`

should produce `(x.y)`, but it removes the brackets and just gives `x.y`. Is there a command to output brackets? Similarly, can I do the same but with square brackets?

Comment: `Format[f[x_, y_]] := 
 RowBox[{"(", (x\[CenterDot]y), ")"}] // DisplayForm` ?

Comment: That's perfect thanks

Comment: Also, `Format[f[x_, y_]] := StringForm["(``)", x\[CenterDot]y]`